# Unable to remove TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have just started learning tensorflow coding and I am stuck with very basic code for creating a neural network. Below is the the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np    
a = tf.placeholder(shape=(1,1),dtype=tf.float16)
b = tf.placeholder(shape=(1,1),dtype=tf.float16)
y= tf.placeholder(shape=(1,1),dtype=tf.float16)    
addition = tf.add(a, b)    
correct_prediction = tf.equal(addition,y,name=None)    
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()    
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    a1=[[0.2]]
    b1=[[0.3]]
    y1=[[0.5]]
    a = sess.run(addition, feed_dict={a: a1, b: b1})
    b = sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={a: a1, b: b1, y: y1})
sess.close()
```

It is giving me the following error

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/NN/pyNN/new_main.py", line 35, in <module>
    b = sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={a: a1, b: b1, y: y1})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'*
```

I have tried multiple ways for providing the input and output but I end up with the same error. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning the result of `session.run()` to `a`. This means `a` is a numpy array after the first `run`, overwriting the original definition as a placeholder. Then you are using this array as a key in the dictionary for the second `run`, which obviously doesn't work.

Renaming the `a` and `b` variables within the session context should fix it, e.g.

```
a_array = sess.run(addition, feed_dict={a: a1, b: b1})
b_array = sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={a: a1, b: b1, y: y1})
```

Comment: Iv'e voted this up since it's a correct answer, but it's much better to have an answer with an example \ solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added a fix to the answer.